# How to stick the document's border to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to code a sticky footer using the html object, in HTML and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242136/how-to-code-a-sticky-footer-using-the-html-object-in-html-and-css)

I'm applying a 10px border both to the top and bottom of the `html` object, using the below (LESS) CSS. It only works when the document is taller than the viewport, though.

This is [what's happening](http://prikonline.be/prikactie/) right now. As you can see, the `border-bottom` sticks to the bottom of `html`, but doesn't stick to the bottom of the window.

I've already tried to stuff `html` and `body` with `height: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 100%;`, but it doesn't seem to work at all. Any suggestions?

```
html {
    border-top: solid @black 10px;
    border-bottom: solid @black 10px;
    background: url('img/bg.png') repeat;
}

body {
    width: @8col;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 100px 48px 84px;
    background: @white;
    font: 13px/20px 'OftenRegular';
    color: rgb(60,60,60);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: @green;
}
```