# CSS: Make a border stay at the bottom of the page (not window)

Tags: html, css, border

I've got a simple page, and I'm trying to set a border on the bottom of my page's body in CSS like so:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom-color: #ad3127;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

This works great if I've got enough content to fill the whole window, especially when it needs to scroll: the bar appears at the bottom of the page (not the window. I don't want it to be floating over content or anything like that).

The problem is when there's not enough content to fill up the whole window, the bar just appears at the bottom of whereever the content ends. This sort of makes sense, but it's obviously not what I want.

I've tried something like

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Which seems to work in both cases, except when I resize my window it gets mangled (at least in Firefox 4) and in Mobile Safari it renders at the bottom of my viewport (ie kind of just in the middle of my content). So this does not appear to be doing it for me.

There must be a way to solve this (with as little sorcery as possible, please :)).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242136/how-to-code-a-sticky-footer-using-the-html-object-in-html-and-css/6243335#6243335

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `height: 100%`, use `min-height: 100vh`:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #ad3127;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>content</p>
```

Because of `box-sizing: border-box`, border of the body will be accounted in the body height. The only hack here is for content margins pushing the border below viewport, which is fixed with an arbitrary `padding-top` value.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier did an interesting article on body borders a while back. Here is the link for reference: http://css-tricks.com/558-body-border/

To do what you want, the most cross browser way would be to create a div that acts like a border, and then give it a fixed position of bottom 0. Something to this effect:

```
HTML: 
<div id="bottom"></div>

CSS:
#bottom {
    background: #ad3127;
    height: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

A little bit less hacky way, albiet less compatible with older browsers is to use pseudo elements:

```
body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: #ad3127;
    height: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I originally read your question wrong and didn't realize that you didn't want it floating over content. I think what you want is a sticky footer. Here is a site that has a solution even on browser resize, though I have not tested it out: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: These solutions are both for a bar which stays stuck at the bottom of the *viewport* (ie Window), and not the bottom of the page, which is what I'm trying to do. That is, if there's a ton of content, I want to be able to scroll to the bottom of the page, and then see the border. If there's not enough content to scroll, I'm trying to have the bottom border be at the bottom of the window. I can seem to do either or but not both.

Comment: Looks like we both commented at the same time. CSS Sticky Footer appears to be doing what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Alas this is too much of a hack.